# Can anyone help me with what set these bags belong to? Black parts galore

Tags: set-identification

I have bags number 5,6,7. I think they may all be to the same set. The QR code is not coming up with anything.
[image: black parts galore]

Answer (score 8):

I can peek a couple of [12L red axle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3708&idColor=5)s plus a [trans-green projectile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15303&idColor=108).

That and the sheer amount of black parts is enough to identify this as [75256-1 Kylo Ren's Shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75256-1) from the Star Wars franchise:

[image: set image]

Comment: Thank you so much!